# Should I need babelcore for using import tag

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to use the "import" tag for just defining the template. I'll just change templateUrl in my directive to the template. But it gives an error like 
 "Unexpected identifier" for the import line. So should I use babelcore. Because it transforms es6 to js.

> import template from '../templates/template.html';

In my directive, I'm using like that

```
return {
    restrict: 'ECA',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template:template,
    scope: {}
}
```

Comment: As far as i understand you are trying to import an html file. Usually in javascript html files are rendered via `fs` module

Comment: what is fs module. yes I want to import just html.

Comment: https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/fs/ ^

Comment: This has nothing to do with using babel or not. What module loader or bundler are you using? That's the one you need to tell how to import `.template` files (presumably as string?).